# How do I get rid of the "u" from a decoded JSON object?

Tags: python

I have a dictionary of dictionaries in Python:

```
d = {"a11y_firesafety.html":{"lang:hi": {"div1": "http://a11y.in/a11y/idea/a11y_firesafety.html:hi"}, "lang:kn": {"div1": "http://a11y.in/a11ypi/idea/a11y_firesafety.html:kn}}}
```

I have this in a JSON file and I encoded it using `json.dumps()`. Now when I decode it using `json.loads()` in Python I get a result like this:

```
temp = {u'a11y_firesafety.html': {u'lang:hi': {u'div1': u'http://a11y.in/a11ypi/idea/a11y_firesafety.html:hi'}, u'lang:kn': {u'div1': u'http://a11y.in/a11ypi/idea/a11y_firesafety.html:kn'}}}
```

My problem is with the "u" which signifies the Unicode encoding in front of every item in my temp (dictionary of dictionaries). How to get rid of that "u"?

Comment: Why do you need that? Just for comparing the two dictionaries of for another purpose?

Comment: Are the unicode strings that you get after `json.loads()` actually a problem for you?

Comment: You could upgrade to Python 3, which no longer makes such a distinction.  :-)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Why do you care about the 'u' characters?  They're just a visual indicator; unless you're actually using the result of `str(temp)` in your code, they have no effect on your code.  For example:

```
>>> test = u"abcd"
>>> test == "abcd"
True
```

If they do matter for some reason, and you don't care about consequences like not being able to use this code in an international setting, then you could pass in a custom `object_hook` (see the [json](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html#json.load) docs here) to produce dictionaries with string contents rather than unicode.

Comment: But is there a way to get rid of them?

Comment: For me, I care because I want to copy and paste it to a text editor and format the results.

Answer (score 3):

You could also use this:

```
import fileinput

fout = open("out.txt", 'a')

for i in fileinput.input("in.txt"):

   str = i.replace("u\"","\"").replace("u\'","\'")

   print >> fout,str
```

The typical json responses from standard websites have these two encoding representations - u' and u"
This snippet gets rid of both of them. It may not be required as this encoding doesn't hinder any logical processing, as mentioned by previous commenter

Comment: after trying all the decode and encode options, this one only helped me :)

Comment: I figured out an easier and more reliable/advisable way of doing this. Just use json.dumps(resp) where resp is your api response.   Note: You will need json library i.e."import json".                  To eliminate trailing spaces you could further add json.dumps(resp).strip()

Answer (score 2):

There is no "unicode" encoding, since unicode is a different data type and I don't really see any reason unicode would be a problem, since you may always convert it to string doing e.g. `foo.encode('utf-8')`.

However, if you really want to have string objects upfront you should probably create your own [decoder class](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html#encoders-and-decoders) and use it while decoding JSON.